# The HTML is not updating on Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrive the HTML of element on click. This is the snippet

```js
$( () => {
  $( document ).on('click', 'button', function(){
    const html = $('table').html();
    console.log( html );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input 1</th>
      <th>Input 2</th>
      <th>Input 3</th>
      <th>Input 4</th>
      <th>Input 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Clone table!</button>
```

If I set a new value on the input element of each row, I expect a table HTML with input's value attribute with the correct strings

I don't know why the DOM is not updating, I added changes to the table's HTML, and it looks like as not changes. I tried to find the changes on different indexes and functions

```
$('table')[0].outerHTML
$('table')[0].innerHTML
$('table').clone().html()
$('table').html()
```

No one has the correct HTML. If I browse on the developer tools -> Elements tab I see the changes, but I can't retrieve them.

What do you propouse?

Comment: What do you expect as result of your function? Because right now, looking at your first snippet, it is returning what is expected to. the element HTML will not be updated with the `value` property, it will be a property of the element, but not of the DOM

Comment: The current HTML after click and set new input's value

Comment: What about clone the rows of a table, 100 rows, but with inputs inside with different data of the original data

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it represents exactly what do I want.

Comment: "*I set a new value on the input element of each row*" - how are you doing this?  That's the relevant part of the code/question.

Comment: I want to copy exactly the table, with rows, values, inputs to store it on a database. If the user turn off his browser or machine, and he pressed the button, save the entry table. I know, this is not the best way to do, but is the requirement of the client.

Comment: yes, it's not the best way by far... usually you would save only the data, and the table would be dynamically build based on data (or empty if no data), but if it is client requirement, then let's think a solution

Comment: *"but is the requirement of the client"* - is it?  sounds like an XY problem or a misinterpretation.  Did the "client" really ask you to "save the entire HTML" or did they add a **business requirement**, eg "restore the table if they clicked save" and storing the HTML is your *solution* to that requirement.  If this is the case, then consider a different, more tenable solution (ie store the data).

Comment: Actually the requirement comes from client's architect's software. I told with him and I showed him the beneficts to store only the data, with JSON, with XHR, re-built on session starts, etc ... but he want to save the complete table. They want to do a "big data" (I know what are you thinking, I think the same haha)

Answer (score 2):

See comment inline:

```js
$( () => {
  $( document ).on('click', 'button', function(){
    // Set the value attribute in the HTML to the entered value
    $("input").attr("value", $("input").val());
    const html = $('div').html();
    console.log( html );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, but this is not what I'm looking for, I updated my question, sorry for my bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** You would have to map each field value to an array and set the values as attributes on the clone.

So, you can follow this pattern for other input like e.g. `select`.

- `serializeSelectValues` – access and store the values
- `applySerializedSelect` – apply the values

**Note:** If you want to handle advanced cloning, you will need to provide names with your input fields.

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.reduce = function(callback, initial) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, callback, initial)
  }
  $.fn.serializeInputValues = function() {
    return this.find('input').reduce((valueArr, input, index) => {
      return valueArr.concat($(input).val())
    }, [])
  }
  $.fn.applySerializedInput = function(serialized) {
    this.find('input').each((index, input) => {
      if (serialized[index]) $(input).attr('value', serialized[index])
    })
    return this
  }
  $.fn.cloneSerialized = function() {
    return this.clone().applySerializedInput(this.serializeInputValues())
  }
})(jQuery)

$(() => {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('body').append($('.serializable').cloneSerialized())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="serializable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input 1</th>
      <th>Input 2</th>
      <th>Input 3</th>
      <th>Input 4</th>
      <th>Input 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Clone table!</button>
```

A note on `$.fn.clone` from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

> **Note:** For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements.

---

Alternatively... avoid input fields entirely.

This way you can grab the text value of each cell without all the messy work.

```js
$(() => {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('body').append($('.serializable').clone())
  })
});
```

```css
td { border: thin solid grey }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="serializable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input 1</th>
      <th>Input 2</th>
      <th>Input 3</th>
      <th>Input 4</th>
      <th>Input 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
      <td contenteditable=true></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Clone table!</button>
```

Comment: Awesome answer Polywhirl, but, What happens, if the table on the rows has checkboxes, radios, text, images, buttons, etc... I want to retrieve all the table content as HTML (With the current updates of inputs, textareas, checked checkboxes etc). A copy exactly as I see but in HTML

Comment: "What happens if..." then you add that to your question when you ask it if it's relevant.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, I wrote I want to get the HTML of the current view, not loop the rows, and then rebuild the inputs... etc. Don't be angry with me :(

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob essentially, you can't do what you want in a single command such as `$("table").cloneWithAllValuesMagicallyExactlyHowIWantIt()` as it doesn't do what you want.  So one solution, as provided here, is to give you that functionality.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob I have a suggestion... set the `<TD>` elements to `contenteditable=true` and then you can just grab the raw HTML (as is).